# Binary files and funcstion fread with Structures dynamical char array

Tags: c++11

When I write down an array of structures into the binary file, and then read it everything works percfectly,

```
struct Name
{
char *firstname;
char* secondname;
}
```

but when I comment out fwrite function, after testings I realised that the main issue is in denamic char arrays, when replace it with the static char array - everything ok, why does it happend?

```
errno_t err = fopen_s(&f, "FinancialDepartment.txt", "wb+");
    if (err)
    {
        cerr << err << " " << stderr << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    fwrite(&Financial, sizeof(Department),1 ,f);
        fclose(f);
```

and then tries to read the information directly from the existing file,

```
errno_t err = fopen_s(&f, "FinancialDepartment.txt", "rb+");
    if (err)
    {
        cerr << err << " " << stderr << endl;
        printf( "errno = %d\n", err );
        exit(1);
    }
        size_t result=fread(&Financial, sizeof(Department), 1,f);
        if (result != 1)
        {
            cout<<"Error";
            exit (3);
        }
fclose(f);
}
```

and then tries as in previous case to print it  - here is an error

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const char *_Val)
    {   // insert NTBS into char stream
```

Could you please advice me, why this issue arrises just in that case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the actual error. All you have there is a partial function definition. Also, post the code where you're printing the value of the data read in.

Comment: The main issue here was that in structure were created pointers to a dynamic char arrays, thats why in file wrote down only pointers but not the arrays.